# Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is a spring boot 2 application.

An entity having 2 named queries, which is throwing exception while starting the server like "`Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping EstCredentials.findAppDepartment`"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = EntityConstants.TABLE_EST_CREDENTIALS)
@NamedNativeQueries({

        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Credentials.findAppDepartment", query = "SELECT (deptmast.deptid) as deptId, deptname as deptName"
                + " FROM deptmast, doctdept" + " WHERE deptmast.deptid = doctdept.deptid ", resultSetMapping = "APP_DEPARTMENT"),
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Credentials.findAppClinic", query = "SELECT   A.DOCTDEPTID as doctdeptId, A.DOCTDEPTNAME as doctDeptName, "
                + " FROM DOCTDEPT A, DEPTMAST B" 
                + "  WHERE A.WORKING = 1", resultSetMapping = CommonConstants.APP_CLINIC_RESULT_MAP) })


@SqlResultSetMappings({
        @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "APP_DEPARTMENT", classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = InstituteDepartmentDto.class, columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "deptId", type = Long.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "deptName", type = String.class) }) }),
        @SqlResultSetMapping(name = CommonConstants.APP_CLINIC_RESULT_MAP, classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = InstituteDoctorDepartmentDto.class, columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "docDeptId", type = Long.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "doctDeptname", type = String.class) }) })

})

public class Credentials {

    private Long estCode;
    private String dbUserName;
    private String dbPassword;


    public Credentials() {

    }

}
```

Let me know if need any other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it pays to assume that error messages are right.

In this case, you have a duplicate mapping for a query named: "EstCredentials.findAppDepartment". You defined this name in CommonConstants.APP_DEPARTMENT_RESULT_MAP and then use it twice, for two different mappings.

Comment: Updated the code. But I haven't use that name APP_DEPARTMENT any where else. Tried changing it to APP_DEPARTMENT2, Still same error.

Comment: Defined in another file same mapping. That was the issue

Comment: @user630209: so... that is exactly what my answer was? you defined CommonConstants.APP_DEPARTMENT_RESULT_MAP to be "EstCredentials.findAppDepartment" and used it twice. It's also the same thing that the error message said...

Comment: Random - I had a similar issue because IntelliJ needed its cache cleared (Action -> Invalidate Cache and Restart).  I had NOT duplicated anything...